# What should the entry point for a signature field look like?

Tags: forms, input-fields, tablet

I'm designing a form for a permission approval feature that will be used on tablets. this will require the user to sign their request.

My question is, is there a way to indicate that the field at the bottom of the form requires signature input(the actual signing will open in a popup with a pen tool, so the user can use the full screen to sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but here is how the digital document sign app we are using looks like:

[image]